# How can I toggle show hide playback controls in AVplayerController with one button?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I made my app with AVplayer and control video with function seeks to time

when I tap the button to seek, the player control won't show, but when I tap on the video layer It will show.

How can I make my button to toggle to show player control?

here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
    self.avpController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.avpController.player = self.player
    avpController.view.frame = viewPlayer.frame
    self.addChild(avpController)
    self.view.addSubview(avpController.view)
    self.player.play()
}

@IBAction func btnSeek(_ sender: Any) {
    let seconds : Int64 = Int64(20)
    let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
    player.seek(to: targetTime)
}
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: FYI your code is illegal. After `addChild` and `addSubview` you _must_ call `didMoveToParent`.

Comment: After some researches, I found there is a design consideration for such behavior. You may not need to hack the way of AVPlayerController. It you really need some customization, use AVPlayerLayer to achieve your own goal.